# EPROMs /OE switching Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, resistors, circuit-design, diodes, eprom

For a personal project I'm trying to make a reproduction of a SNES game (Earthbound) which is 3mb in size.
Now the easiest way would be fitting the game in a 4mb 27C322 and multiplex the 16 bit bus to 8 bit (there are even pre-made PCBs that take care of the wiring and multiplexing).

However I'm trying to do it by myself, for fun, and with the components I already have at home.
This is the schematic I came up with:

[image: eprom selector circuit]

Basically I'm using 2 OR gates to combine the output effects of /OE and (inverted)A21 on the eproms and select the correct chip.

Now, I'm by no means an expert in electronics (as you may also have guessed by how I did the schematic) and unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope to test it by myself, so my question is: **will this circuit commute fast enough?**

By "Fast enough" I mean in a time ideally =< 120ns (the fastrom specs of the SNES) and mandatorily =< 140ns (the actual time the SNES expect the signals to be stable). Anything over would be trying my luck hoping the components perform better than what the datasheet reports.

If I do the math (from the datasheets) the eproms are both 100ns, the 74F04 inverter is 3.5ns and the 1N5819 is 10ns (on some datasheets, on others I read =< 500ns?!). IF the forward recovery time is always less than the reverse (correct me on this if I'm wrong) it *should* work.

**My doubts are about the 4.7kohm resistor**, again, correct me if I'm wrong, but in this circuit the higher the resistance the slower the transition from 1 to 0 will be, but if the resistance is too low, I'm afraid that the opposite will also be true: transitioning from 0 to 1 will require more time.
4.7kohm is a "good enough" pull-up/down resistor for 5v TTL in most cases, but can it work in this case where there could be many fast commutations from 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1?

Comment: What rise/fall time the components need and does it still fulfill the timing requirements how fast the stable data is needed? It just looks awkward when you use F series TTL chips for super fast speeds and then you let a 4k7 pull-up resistor to pull the voltage slowly down. It migh be worth to change the F04 to eg. an address decoder or some other gate.

Comment: 100ns the eprom, 3.5ns the inverter and 10ns the diode(trr), so 113.5ns.
Original SNES maskroms have a response time of 120ns (at least the fastrom variant that is the one I need), but the SNES actually needs the lines stabilized in 140ns so this is my maximum. Using an OR gate IC will be more appropriate, but I don't have any. The combination of components is ackward because this is what I have right now and, apart from that, I'm curious to know if it is achievable. I have plenty of resistors however, so picking a different value is not a problem if that helps to commute the circuit faster..